Builodzer generative ai import bug
I am building android apk using buildozer, but the apk crashes when i open it on my android device. The problem is with importing google-generative ai in my main.py. Here is the full code:
Main.py
import os
import google.generativeai as genai
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserListView
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.utils import platform
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE
from docx.shared import Pt
from kivy.lang import Builder


if platform == 'android':
    from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
    from android.storage import primary_external_storage_path
    from jnius import autoclass

    # Requesting permissions
    def callback(permission, results):
        if all([res for res in results]):
            # Permission granted, proceed with file path setup
            setup_file_path()
        else:
            # Permission denied, handle appropriately
            print("Permission denied")

    def setup_file_path():
        global file_path
        file_path = os.path.join(primary_external_storage_path(), 'Docs')
        if not os.path.exists(file_path):
            os.makedirs(file_path)

    # Initializing file_path with an empty string
    file_path = ''

    request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE], callback)
else:
    file_path = os.path.expanduser('~/')

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()

I am unable to post by whole buildozer.spec here but I am posting the requirements i am using.
Right now, I am debugging the code, so I change it to a simple apk and import the required modules, apk works fine if i do not import google-generativeai.
Following are the requirements i provided in buildozer.spec:
requirements = python3,kivy,jnius,python-docx==1.1.2,typing-extensions==4.12.2,lxml==5.2.2,google-generativeai==0.6.0,protobuf==4.25.3,pydantic,google-auth>=2.15.0,google-ai-generativelanguage==0.6.4,tqdm==4.66.4,google-api-python-client==2.132.0,google-api-core==2.19.0,proto-plus==1.23.0,pyasn1-modules==0.4.0,cachetools==5.3.3,rsa==4.9,requests==2.32.2,googleapis-common-protos==1.63.1,httplib2==0.20.2,google-auth-httplib2==0.2.0,uritemplate==4.1.1,pydantic-core==2.18.4,annotated-types==0.7.0,grpcio==1.64.0,grpcio-status==1.62.2
Please tell me if this is correct and what can i do to fix this bug
I am using the following command to build my apk:
Buildozer -v android debug

Not familiar with generativeai, but if it uses the internet, then your app will require that permission.

One of the reasons from the crash is coming from the function below:
def setup_file_path():
    global file_path
    file_path = os.path.join(primary_external_storage_path(), 'Docs')
    if not os.path.exists(file_path):
        os.makedirs(file_path)

The app attempts to create a folder called Docs in the device storage, this should work fine in Android 6 but I tried in Android 12 and it crashes due to that error, the way to create the folder should change to a system file browser as a callback or with an app local directory.
In your case, maybe the buildozer.spec file needs specific libraries, sharing what I used and the APK compiled successfully and it successfully started, you can add any missing libraries here:
requirements = kivy==2.3.0,kivymd==0.104.1,python3,pyjnius,plyer,requests,urllib3,chardet,idna,pip,Image,PIL,android,watchdog,google-generativeai

App compiled:

App in an Android 12 phone:

Final code:
import os

try:
    import google.generativeai as genai
except:
    pass
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserListView
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.utils import platform
try:
    from docx import Document
    from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE
    from docx.shared import Pt
except:
    pass
from kivy.lang import Builder
#import google.generativeai as genai

if platform == 'android':
    from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
    from android.storage import primary_external_storage_path
    from jnius import autoclass

    # Requesting permissions
    def callback(permission, results):
        if all([res for res in results]):
            # Permission granted, proceed with file path setup
            setup_file_path()
        else:
            # Permission denied, handle appropriately
            print("Permission denied")

    def setup_file_path():
        global file_path
        file_path = os.path.join(primary_external_storage_path(), 'Docs')
        if not os.path.exists(file_path):
            os.makedirs(file_path)

    # Initializing file_path with an empty string
    file_path = ''

    request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE], callback)
else:
    file_path = os.path.expanduser('~/')

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()

Mainly the issue came from the error:
07-18 15:01:09.714 27638 27638 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
07-18 15:01:09.715 27638 27638 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_proxy.pxi", line 50, in jnius.jnius.PythonJavaClass.invoke
07-18 15:01:09.715 27638 27638 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_proxy.pxi", line 76, in jnius.jnius.PythonJavaClass._invoke
07-18 15:01:09.715 27638 27638 I python  :    File "/home/jbsidis/Desktop/j3/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/GenAI/armeabi-v7a/android/permissions.py", line 472, in onRequestPermissionsResult
07-18 15:01:09.716 27638 27638 I python  :    File "/home/jbsidis/Desktop/j3/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/GenAI/armeabi-v7a/android/permissions.py", line 555, in python_callback
07-18 15:01:09.716 27638 27638 I python  :    File "/home/jbsidis/Desktop/j3/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 33, in callback
07-18 15:01:09.716 27638 27638 I python  :    File "/home/jbsidis/Desktop/j3/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 42, in setup_file_path
07-18 15:01:09.716 27638 27638 I python  :    File "<frozen os>", line 225, in makedirs
07-18 15:01:09.716 27638 27638 I python  :  PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/storage/emulated/0/Docs'
07-18 15:03:26.158 29213 29268 V pythonutil: Unpacking private app

